# Suppressing traceback (stack trace) for caught exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception

I have python code that catches an exception:

```
# ...
except Exception:
    # Handle the exception
```

When this code is executed, the traceback (stack trace) is printed to the console. How can I suppress it?

Comment: Show the rest of the handling code... it shouldn't be printed.

Comment: How are you running this code?  Can you post the stack trace that gets printed?  Are you sure you're catching the exception?  Normally Python will only print a stack trace for exceptions that make it to the program's entry point.

Comment: Ah you sure the exception that's being printed is the original exception? If another exception happens inside your exception handler, it will propagate outwards and it can sometimes be difficult to spot that it's not the original cause of things going wrong.

Comment: @Ben I think you are right. I think that is what is happening.

Comment: an old question, I know, but this is at least the answer I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27674608/2184122

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not recommended, but

```
except Exception:
    pass
```

Will silently ignore the exception.  However, if you don't fix what went wrong, your program may quit anyways because something further down in your code will throw another exception.  You should at the least print out a message stating what happened, or debugging your code can be a nightmare.

Comment: Well, I want to handle the exception but I don't want the stack trace to print. In Java, the stack trace prints when the printStackTrace method is called. Not calling that method suppresses the stack trace being printed, however, I am not sure how that's done in Python.

Comment: The given code will skip the stack trace printing.  The python analog to `printStackTrace` is [sys.exc_info](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info).