# Hide traceback unless a debug flag is set

Tags: python, error-handling, user-experience

What is the idiomatic python way to hide traceback errors unless a verbose or debug flag is set?

Example code:

```
their_md5 = 'c38f03d2b7160f891fc36ec776ca4685'
my_md5 = 'c64e53bbb108a1c65e31eb4d1bb8e3b7' 
if their_md5 != my_md5:
    raise ValueError('md5 sum does not match!')
```

Existing output now, but only desired when called with `foo.py --debug`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\code\apt\apt.py", line 1647, in <module>
    __main__.__dict__[command] (packages)
  File "b:\code\apt\apt.py", line 399, in md5
    raise ValueError('md5 sum does not match!')
ValueError: md5 sum does not match!
```

Desired normal output:

```
ValueError: md5 sum does not match!
```

Here's a test script: https://gist.github.com/maphew/e3a75c147cca98019cd8

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The short way is using the `sys` module and use this command:

```
sys.tracebacklimit = 0
```

Use your flag to determine the behaviour.

Example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.tracebacklimit=0
>>> int('a')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

The nicer way is to use and [exception hook](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook):

```
def exception_handler(exception_type, exception, traceback):
    # All your trace are belong to us!
    # your format
    print "%s: %s" % (exception_type.__name__, exception)

sys.excepthook = exception_handler
```

### Edit:

If you still need the option of falling back to the original hook:

```
def exception_handler(exception_type, exception, traceback, debug_hook=sys.excepthook):
    if _your_debug_flag_here:
        debug_hook(exception_type, exception, traceback)
    else:
        print "%s: %s" % (exception_type.__name__, exception)
```

Now you can pass a debug hook to the handler, but you'll most likely want to always use the one originated in `sys.excepthook` (so pass nothing in `debug_hook`). Python binds default arguments **once** in definition time (common pitfall...) which makes this always work with the same original handler, before replaced.

Comment: thank you! I'm having difficulty implementing the nicer way though. It's perfect for the user friendly response, but I haven't been able to do it verbosely. `print traceback` just shows object name and `dir(traceback)` doesn't show anything I know what to do with. Here's what I have: https://gist.github.com/maphew/e3a75c147cca98019cd8

Comment: Rev5 of the [sample gist](https://gist.github.com/maphew/e3a75c147cca98019cd8/7236687e4161b2c3c5eca0daec500a516cc21055) has a complete working example. Thanks again Reut.

Comment: Beautiful solution. You can make it into a one-liner using a lambda: `sys.excepthook = lambda exctype,exc,traceback : print("{}: {}".format(exctype.__name__,exc))`

Comment: python3 alert: The above example with `sys.tracebacklimit = 0` does not work. However, the defined (and insightful!) function `exceptionHandler` works just fine, with the usual change in print.

Comment: Instead of relying on `sys.excepthook` not beeing re-defined at function definition time, you can use `sys.__excepthook__`, which always keeps its original definition, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6598286/512111).

Comment: This really should be the default behaviour - adding a page of traceback makes the user less likely to look any error message, so is quite counter productive unless you are the actual developer of the code.

Answer (score 6):

```
try:
    pass # Your code here
except Exception as e:
    if debug:
        raise # re-raise the exception
              # traceback gets printed
    else:
        print("{}: {}".format(type(e).__name__, e))
```

Comment: that yields `TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType` for me (py v2.7.4 at the moment)

Comment: @matt: in which line? I don't have 2.7.4, so I cannot see the error.

Comment: my mistake, I had `if debug: raise` outside of the `except ... as e:` block. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27680034/14420) now works in http://repl.it/languages/Python/. +1 for something that works, but I'm accepting Reut's answer because I'd prefer not to have to wrap everything in _try:...except:_.

Answer (score 1):

Use the logging system to handle the error output.

I'll use requests connection error as an example use case, it generates a cascade of 3 exceptions each with a lengthy traceback. Only the final error message is of real importance - the called service is refusing, I don't need to know 3 pages of traceback from my client app!

1. Define a custom error class

```py
# file: custom_exceptions.py

class Error(Exception):
    """This class should be used where traceback should not be logged"""
    pass
```

2. In the inner function, catch the exception and cast it to the custom error class

```py
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        raise custom_exceptions.Error(e)
```

3. Handle the custom exception and unexpected exceptions differently in the caller function

```py
    except custom_exceptions.Error as e:    # any custom error based on the custom Error class
        if LOGLEVEL=logging.DEBUG:
            logger.exception(e)     # with traceback
        else:
            logger.error(e)         # just the exception and message
        exit()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)         # with traceback
        exit()
```

The resultant log message - all the detail you need for this error scenario:

```
2021-07-23 10:58:27,545 [ERROR] HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /next (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc54f11f9d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```