# How do I suppress tracebacks in Jupyter?

Tags: python, exception, jupyter-notebook

I want to hide tracebacks in my Python code in Jupyter notebooks, so only the error type and message are displayed.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27674608/1013457) suggests `sys.tracebacklimit = 0` but trying that gave the following:

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last): 
AssertionError 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
AssertionError
```

That answer also suggests replacing `sys.excepthook` with a custom function, but the traceback was still displayed.

How can I hide the traceback?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found a couple ways to do this, both involving monkeypatching IPython.

#1. This will output just the exception type and message but highlighted in red in the output area:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # for python 2 compatibility
import sys
ipython = get_ipython()

def exception_handler(exception_type, exception, traceback):
    print("%s: %s" % (exception_type.__name__, exception), file=sys.stderr)

ipython._showtraceback = exception_handler
```

#2. This will output the exception and color code the exception type (just like Jupyter normally does, but without the traceback):

```
import sys
ipython = get_ipython()

def hide_traceback(exc_tuple=None, filename=None, tb_offset=None,
                   exception_only=False, running_compiled_code=False):
    etype, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    value.__cause__ = None  # suppress chained exceptions
    return ipython._showtraceback(etype, value, ipython.InteractiveTB.get_exception_only(etype, value))

ipython.showtraceback = hide_traceback
```

Comment: You also need to add `from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython`

Answer (score 8):

I think the `xmode` magic is what you are looking for here. Just type it in a cell. There are four modes: Context, Minimal, Verbose and Plain(the default I think). you can either use `xmode <mode>` or with no argument it toggles to the next mode.

```
In [1]: %xmode
Exception reporting mode: Minimal

In [2]: %xmode
Exception reporting mode: Plain
```

Here is the difference with a simple error. It becomes easier to see the differences with more detailed error messages.

`xmode Minimal`

```
x = 6 / 0
```

returns

```
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

`xmode plain`

```
x = 6 / 0


Traceback (most recent call last):
                                                                        
File "<ipython-input-187-28f66aec0cca>", line 2, in <module>
x = 6/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero




%xmode Plain
<PRE>pd.read_csv("foo.bar")
%xmode Context
pd.read_csv("foo.bar")
%xmode Verbose
pd.read_csv("foo.bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

what about

```py
import functools
import IPython

ipython = IPython.core.getipython.get_ipython()
method_name = "showtraceback"
setattr(
    ipython,
    method_name,
    functools.partial(
        getattr(ipython, method_name),
        exception_only=True
    )
)
```

Comment: or something like this: https://gist.github.com/waszil/fccda8749ed5dd5baa336bae8e88dd7a