# Avoid seeing error message twice when raising error in python

Tags: python

I would like my python program to raise an error:

```
import os

if not os.path.isdir(args.sample_dir):
    raise OSError('Samples not found.')
```

When running the code, I receive the following error when the above requirement is met:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/blade/utils.py", line 696, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/blade/utils.py", line 663, in main
    raise OSError('Samples not found.')
OSError: Samples not found.
```

I don't like that I see the error sentence twice. Is there a way to hide the earlier one from log?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide traceback unless a debug flag is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674602/hide-traceback-unless-a-debug-flag-is-set)

Comment: Yes, it is difficult to follow! I think [this](https://gist.github.com/maphew/e3a75c147cca98019cd8) is the final answer, from the OP's first comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks, a difference (correct me if I'm wrong) is that when I use sys.tracebacklimit = 0 it will limit all my error outputs to that one line, whereas I'm just intending to apply it for the error that I specifically raised an error. I'll check the link to make sure I'm not wrong

Comment: @KenY-N Actually, I think this is right, I should just put sys.tracebacklimit = 0 inside my if statement, that way it only applies to that particular error! Thanks for your help!

Comment: On `ipython3`, `sys.tracebacklimit = 0` dumped out a huge wall of text for me...

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you can use try/except for ignoring one of the error.
try:
os.path.isdir(args.sample_dir)
except
raise OSError('Samples not found.')

Comment: This is not good advice. OP wants to check if the value returned by `os.path.isdir()` is `True` or `False`, not if the call itself raises an exception. Also, it's almost always a bad decision to use an unqualified `except` (i can think of one case where it's ok, and this ain't it).