# Python csv reader, check for missing headers gracefully

Tags: python

I'm reading a csv file exactly like below:

| HEADER1 | HEADER2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | row1 |
| Second | row2 |

Now I need to check if it has any missing "headers" like HEADER1 or HEADER2 based on my `inc_headers`.

```
inc_headers = ['HEADER1','HEADER2','HEADER3']

def validatefields():
    inc_missing = []
    incident_reader = csv.DictReader(open(incident_path))
    for line in incident_reader:
        for field in inc_headers:
            if line[field]:
                pass
            else:
                inc_missing.append(field)
            continue
        break
```

In example above, I'm trying to see if HEADER3 is there and it should just append the `field` to the `inc_missing` list. Instead, the program breaks with an error. The program just completely breaks down and no longer follows the `else` or the `except` clause. I've also tried the `try` syntax below and it will still throw an error. How do I capture this error gracefully?

```
try:
    x = line[field]
except:
    ....
```

Comment: It's not a "traceback error". "traceback" is additional information that is associated with the error. You should show it here.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it shows my inexperience in the new things I apologize. I'm coming from mf-rpgle

Answer (score 0):

Codeblock below will fix the issue. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674602/hide-traceback-unless-a-debug-flag-is-set)

```
sys.tracebacklimit = 0
try: 
    line[field]
except Exception as e:
    inc_missing.append(field)
```